# Making a shorter minus

Tags: math-mode

I am doing some display typography with an equation in it using the `mathpazo` package. At one point I have this fraction:

```
$\sqrt{-\frac{1}{9}}$
```

To me, the minus looks too long. I would like to make it shorter, but use of `\textrm{-}` gives me something that is too thick. Is there a way to get something with the thickness of the minus above, but of a similar length to a hyphen?

Edited to add: this is really for a special case of enormous type on a T-shirt design, and the standard minus sign looks strange. I would not do this for standard use of math in an article.

Comment: You do know that a minus sign is _supposed_ to be longer than a hyphen? More generally, this is part of the font design and it's usually best for non-experts to 'take it or leave it' with a font: if you don't like it, pick another font.

Comment: @Joseph: +1, though I can see why one would prefer the negativity sign to be a bit shorter than the minus (though I'm not that experienced with math typography to know if it makes sense or not).

Comment: @Khaled. See the related discussion here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/typesetting-of-negative-versus-minus

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is really for a special case of enormous type on a T-shirt design, and the standard minus sign looks strange. I would not do this for standard use of math in an article.

Comment: Good point -- and it would be good to mention that in the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Would something as simple as a `\scalebox` do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,graphicx,mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\( \sqrt{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{\( - \)}\frac{1}{9}} \)

% cf.
\( \sqrt{-\frac{1}{9}} \) 
\end{document}
```

Here, I am using the optional argument to `\scalebox` to set the vertical scaling to 1, so that only the horizontal size changes.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that `\scalebox` has an optional argument for the vertical scaling. (It might be worth explaining this in the answer.)

Comment: Simple macro for this: `\newcommand{\unaryminus}{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{\( - \)}}`. Then you can insert a unary minus with `\unaryminus`.

Answer (score 43):

I use `\text{-}` for a shorter minus sign.

Comment: Hi and welcome, this is no minus sign.

Comment: @Johannes_B The question clearly says it's for a t-shirt. So why not use whatever sign as long as it looks ok on a t-shirt?

Comment: @KeksDose At the time of writing, i haven't read the question. My mistake. But still, the answer states that this is a short minus sign, which is not. As some other user could stumble upon this, in a hurry, looking for solutions, he might not read the question as well and should be informed. Of course, if he really is iin a hurry, he might not read my comment.

Answer (score 24):

There is actually a short dash with rounded ends in `amsfonts`. It is called `\dabar@` and it is only used in the definition of `\dasharrow`=`\dashrightarrow` and `\dashleftarrow` (hence the name). 
It looks exactly like a shorter version of the Computer Modern minus sign, and is also compatible with `mathpazo` (which has a nearly identical minus sign).

I'm redeclaring this character below as a binary operator so that its spacing matches that of `-` in all situations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts} %% <- also included by amssymb
\DeclareMathSymbol{\shortminus}{\mathbin}{AMSa}{"39}

\usepackage{mathpazo} %% <- because the OP uses mathpazo, optional

\begin{document}

\[
    -5, \shortminus5
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: mathpazo output]

This is what it looks like with the `mathpazo` line commented out:

[image: cm output]

Comment: I had a similar problem, where I have a figure, with a label that reads "-w". The nomal minus looks freakishly long, but this is just right.

Comment: Best answer to the question. Also, the syntax of (re)declaring symbols as math binary operators looks useful.

Answer (score 8):

for a unary minus that isn't going to be surrounded by a lot of other math -- you did say this would be on a t-shirt -- you might try an en-dash. it's thinner and wider than a hyphen, but at about the same height off the baseline as a hyphen, so you might want to fiddle a bit with the vertical position.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very hackish solution that draws a rule instead:

```
\def\minus{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{-}%
  \vcenter{%
    \hrule width\wd0 height \the\fontdimen8\textfont3%
  }%
}
$$
-A \quad \minus A
$$
\bye
```

Update: a LaTeX version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\minus{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{-}%
  \vcenter{%
    \hrule width\wd0 height \the\fontdimen8\textfont3%
  }%
}
\[
-A \quad \minus A \quad \textrm{-}A
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this solution:

[image: pdflatex of this latex file]

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\-{\raisebox{.75pt}{-}}
\begin{document}
$ -8 \quad \-8 \quad {\scriptstyle -8} $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mind that `\-` is also a command for [hyphenation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Hyphenation).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is best solution for this question.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} 

\DeclareMathSymbol{\shortminus}{\mathbin}{AMSa}{"39}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    -5, \shortminus5
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite curiously, `amssymb` doesn't define a user level name for this symbol. It's defined as `\dabar@` for use in `\dashleftarrow` and `\dashrightarrow`. But you find the same in another answer, namely https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469724/4427