# Narrowing a minus sign in math mode (allowable in for loop)

Tags: tikz-pgf, for-loop

I want to fit the "N-1" into the box below if possible; if I use [the solution `\text{-}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238733/46076), namely `3/{N\text{-}1}`, it gives me an error: `Undefined control sequence: } (followed by: )`

Is there a way to fix?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\def\d{0.7cm} 
\tikzset{
  >=latex,
  font=\sffamily,
  mybox/.style={rectangle, fill=white, thin, draw, outer sep=0, minimum width = \d, minimum height = \d, inner sep=0},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\k/\s in {
             0/1,  3/{N-1},  4/{N}
}{
        \node[mybox] (bc\k) at ($(-\k*\d, 0)$) {$S_{\s}$};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you make your boxes a bit larger?

Comment: The problem is that `\text` isn't defined. Use `\textup` instead of `\text` and it will work.

Comment: `font=\sffamily\small`

Comment: Making the boxes larger is an obvious solution but then the text looks weirdly small (my real example has S0, S1, S2, S3, S4, ... SN-1, SN and the SN-1 is the only one that needs squishing)

Comment: @HoodChatham thanks -- add answer + I'll accept.

Comment: what you will get with `\textup{-}` is a hyphen.  yes, it is narrower than a minus, but it is also not at the same height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\text{-}`, but you need `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\newcommand\dd{0.7cm} 
\tikzset{
  >=latex,
  font=\sffamily,
  mybox/.style={
    rectangle,
    fill=white,
    thin,
    draw, outer sep=0,
    minimum width = \dd,
    minimum height = \dd,
    inner sep=0
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\k/\s in {
             0/1,  3/{N\text{-}1},  4/{N}
}{
        \node[mybox] (bc\k) at ($(-\k*\dd, 0)$) {$S_{\s}$};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Don't do `\def\d{...}`.

[image]

Comment: could you expand on your "Don't do `\def\d`" comment?

Comment: @JasonS Using `\def` is never recommended: you risk redefining important commands without warning and, for this case, head scratching when your bibliography contains exotic names.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that you linked suggests using a `\scalebox` to shrink the minus sign only horizontally instead of vertically. You can define a custom macro like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\sminus{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{\( - \)}}

\begin{document}
  $-8 \sminus 8$
\end{document}
```

To adjust the width of your minus sign to suit your liking, adjust the `{0.75}` value. The `[1.0]` is the vertical scale so that it stays the same "height."