# Better looking quantum states

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, output

I'm having a spacing glitch with the last of these four quantum states, and I'm wondering if there's a way to get a better output:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\kp}[1]{\mskip+#1mu}
\newcommand*{\kn}[1]{\mskip-#1mu}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    |\, 0~0 \, \rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \kp1 (\kp2 |\kn1+ - \kp2 \rangle - |\kn1- + \kp2 \rangle), \\
    |\, 1~1 \, \rangle &= |\kn1+ + \kp2 \rangle, \\
    |\,1~0 \, \rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \kp1 (\kp2 |\kn1+ - \kp2 \rangle + |\kn1- + \kp2 \rangle), \\
    |\, 1\!-\!1 \, \rangle &= |\kn1 - - \kp2 \rangle.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

The last expression is ugly to my eyes, because of the minus sign.  Is there a way to get something that matches the size of the other lines, like a smaller minus sign?

Comment: Use commas and be happy...

Comment: @campa, you mean $|\, 1, -1 \rangle$?  It's still too large compared to others...

Comment: `amssymb` has something which looks like a short minus https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469724/82917

Comment: @campa, is there also a short plus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps not exactly what you want, but too long for a comment.

- I suggest you use `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` to keep the spacing on your ket uniform. You can write `\ket00`, but I recommend `\ket{0}{0}`.
- You can add a `phantom` space to keep your kets aligned. Rather than squeezing a strange small `+` or `-` sign into your last line, I suggest you increase the spacing on the others.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\ket}[2]{\lvert}{\rangle}{\,{#1}\;{#2}\,}
\newcommand{\ps}{\phantom{+}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \ket{0}{\ps0} &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\ket+- -\ket-+),\\
    \ket{1}{\ps1} &=\ket++,\\
    \ket{1}{\ps0} &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\ket+- +\ket-+),\\
    \ket{1}{-1} &=\ket--.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a syntax such as `\qs{a,b}` so we can process the list. In this case, putting between any two items

```
\mathclose{}\;\;\mathopen{}
```

keeps the spacing right and `-1` will be interpreted with unary minus.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\qs}{m}
 {
  \lvert
  \clist_use:nn {#1} {\mathclose{}\;\;\mathopen{}} 
  \rangle
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\qs{0,0}  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\qs{+,-} - \qs{-,+}) \\
\qs{1,1}  &= \qs{+,+} \\
\qs{1,0}  &= \qs{+,-} - \qs{-,+} \\
\qs{1,-1} &= \qs{-,-}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer thin spaces at either end

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\qs}{m}
 {
  \lvert\,
  \clist_use:nn {#1} {\mathclose{}\;\;\mathopen{}} 
  \,\rangle
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\qs{0,0}  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\qs{+,-} - \qs{-,+}) \\
\qs{1,1}  &= \qs{+,+} \\
\qs{1,0}  &= \qs{+,-} - \qs{-,+} \\
\qs{1,-1} &= \qs{-,-}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]