Unsightly minus sign length
When I want to write in subscript -1, I find that the length of the minus sign is unsightly (a bit long) just as I find that the subscript is not low enough which makes reading difficult.

What is the best solution to avoid this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    v&=k_1[A]\\
    v&=k_{-1}[B]
\end{align}
    

\end{document}


An idea: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469724/82917

Yep, probably a duplicate, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469724/38080 seems the best answer to this.
