# Is there a designated symbol for the negative sign in, say, -16?

Tags: math-mode

I've been using `-16` in my LaTeX code to write negative numbers.

But the problem with that, is in many displays and LaTeX rendering kits, it displays the `-` sign as extremely long and separated from all the other mathematical symbols (e.g. the `16`).

Since I knew that LaTeX is an extremely thorough, powerful and complex language, I thought there definitely must be a way to pass this slightly annoying problem.

I don't really want my users looking at a mile-long negative sign.

Is there a way?

Example: [image: I don't want this - too wide and ugly.]

Comment: You've added an image of exactly what I'd expect to see. I was thinking more of your input: that just looks like `$-16$` to me.

Comment: Seems like it is related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6058/making-a-shorter-minus and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/typesetting-of-negative-versus-minus

to make it shorter I use `\text{-}`

Comment: @jenson_bo -- these examples are indeed related.  but the important thing is that the hyphen (what you get with `\text{-}` is *not* equivalent to a minus sign.  better would be an en-dash (`\text{--}`) since it has about the same thickness as a minus, but the vertical positioning is off.

Comment: @barbara beeton --yes, I noticed the difference. In the answer I gave below I used `\scalebox` to get a shorter minus in math mode.

Comment: @jenson_bo -- the nonsymmetric scaling of the minus is a good solution.  +1  but you might want to call it something other than `\minus`, and make it an "ordinary" character to guarantee that the spacing is dependable.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I am not a fan of typing numbers in the text in mathmode. It's fine if you use a complete font, but what if you decide to change the math font later? I prefer to use the `textminus` from the `textcomp` package. If your editor is unicode capable you can enter the proper minus symbol directly.

**Edit:** `siunitx` is able to handle numbers correctly as well.

**Edit 2:** To respond a bit more to the question asked, there is no typographical difference between a 'minus' and 'negative' sign. The difference is the kerning: With `$-12$` the sign is close to the number, with `$10-12$` the minus has appropriate kerning between the numbers. In short, there should be no need to resize the minus sign for negative numbers as a good font should have a minus sign so that its length blends in well with text.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\textminus}% requires a unicode capable editor

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
   detect-mode,
   detect-family,
   detect-inline-family=math,
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Number \textminus10 (textcomp minus)\\
Number −10 (unicode minus)\\% requires a unicode capable editor
Number -10 (normal text minus)\\
Number $-10$ (all math mode)\\    
\vspace{1ex}
\noindent
Number \num{-16} (siunitx textmode. No bug, my bad. Sorry Joseph)\\
Number $\num{-16}$ (siunitx mathmode)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We don't have any context in the question, but in the main I'd expect negative numbers to be more 'mathematical' in usage than 'textual'. For example, something like a temperature is 'mathematical', whereas a section number is 'textual'.

Comment: @JosephWright Not sure I understand what you mean. Would you write something like `today it is $-16$ degrees` in a text?

Comment: It would depend on the context. In something 'textual' (like a letter) I would write it out in words, but in something more 'mathematical' (like a paper for work) I would use `$-16$` (or more likely `siunitx` in math mode).

Comment: @JosephWright Alright, but if you mix something like MinionPro and Euler that would look a little silly. Also, if you define lining numbers for math mode and OSF for text you mix the two in body text, which I think is typographically not correct.

Comment: This is a nice compilation. Could you add the output of `siunitx` to your examples? I am curious how `\num{-10}` looks in comparison. Personally the textcomp minus looks just right.

Comment: @Alexander done

Comment: @JosephWright Could you have a look at my updated MWE. Is that a bug in `siunitx`?

Comment: @Jörg Not a `siunitx` bug: you are not detecting mode, so the package will _always_ use the mode pre-selected. 'Out of the box', numbers are always typeset by `siunitx` in math mode (`\mathnormal`).

Comment: @JosephWright Silly me, sorry. Changed the MWE accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! This should be part of any LaTeX best practices compilation.

Comment: @Jörg: Knuth already discussed this in his [Typesetting Concrete Mathematics](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb10-1/tb23knut.pdf) paper, a nice read.

Comment: Negative numbers are definitely math. A number representing a year or referring to a page is text: those numbers are not used in their mathematical meaning (you don't add/multiply years or page numbers, they're just labels).

Comment: Most importantly, the minus `-` should be just the same as the plus `+` without the vertical stroke. And that's what most fonts do.

Answer (score 24):

David's

> Using a hyphen as in (3) is just horrible, it's all wrong.

got me thinking and I guess a nice alternative (if you don't like the default length) is to define the command `\minus` like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\minus}{\scalebox{0.75}[1.0]{$-$}}

\begin{document}
  $\minus 16$

  $-16$
\end{document}
```

where 0.75 is the horizontal scaling of the box. 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

1: ${}-16$

2: $-16$

3: -$16$

4: $^{-}16$

5: $^{-}\!16$

\end{document}
```

I think the normal usage is as in (2) with the normal length minus sign, If used in prefix position TeX does give it closer spacing than when it is used  as a binary operator (compare with (1) ).

Using a hyphen as in (3) is just horrible, it's all wrong.

It may depend on national customs but here in the UK for educational use it's customary to distinguish the number `-16` from `0 - 16` more clearly so that you can wrote 3 - -16 etc and distinguish the prefix version as part of the number from the infix operator. Using one of (4) or (5) according to taste might be suitable for that usage.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `siunitx` package, it cares about the right sign and font:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgschola}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
   detect-family,
   detect-inline-family=math,
}

\begin{document}
Textmode: \num{-16}

Mathmode: $\num{-16}$

\sffamily
Textmode: \num{-16}

Mathmode: $\num{-16}$

\ttfamily
Textmode: \num{-16}

Mathmode: $\num{-16}$
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: When I add `\usepackage{eulervm}` the first `Textmode: \num{-16}` is set in Euler.

Comment: Not on my system. As far as I know the Euler fonts only use their digits with `euler-digits` option

Comment: As Joseph pointed out above you need `detect-mode` then.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
  -16&--16&-$16$&$-16$\\
  +16&+16&+$16$&$+16$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: comparison of - and --]

The hyphen - from the text font (here Times) does not match the +, but the -- does. On the other hand the minus and plus in math mode match one another. And also one may wish to have the minus and plus match in weight the digits. So either do everything in text mode (and use --) or everything in math mode (perhaps with some math font having shorter minus and plus signs if you can find that rarity...)

Comment: I think that `--` only matches the width of `+` by chance here since `--` produces an en-dash which is a different glyph than a minus sign (which should really have the same width as a plus sign in every font).

Answer (score 2):

A while ago I started to use:

```latex
\newcommand{\p}{\textup{\texttt{+}}} % small unary plus
\newcommand{\m}{\textup{\texttt{-}}} % small unary minus
```

Answer (score 2):

In Unicode, you might use the minus character − (U+2212), rather than the hyphen-minus -.  You might like the former better.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing how all the other answers work, with packages and text and whatnot, it made me think about it and went back and tried the simplest most obvious thing, just put it as an exponent on a blank space, and it worked great. Hopefully this way will be helpful to others.

```
$\ ^-16$

$x = \ ^-16$

$y_2 \geq \ ^-(1 - x_2) $
```

Renders as

[image: Negative sign in latex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. // Sorry, but I haven't seen a minus sign typest like this ever since, not in my lifetime, not in any contemporary or old book. Though the length of the minus sign might be good, its position is not. I recommend deleting or modifying this answer.

Comment: Funny, most of my math teachers made leading negative signs as a sort of prepended exponent.  For what it's worth, why didn't you offer the same comment on David Carlisle's answer above?  I noticed after the fact that he actually did suggest the same thing.