# Is there any specific notation for the negative sign?

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[\displaystyle\int\limits_{1}^{2}(x+2)^\frac{1}{2}-(x+2)^\frac{-1}{2}\;\mathrm{d}x\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I use minus sign instead of negative sign but it looks too long. Is there an alternative symbol or anything like that?

Comment: Not an answer, but I personally find `^{-\frac{1}{2}}` much better

Comment: @Rmano yes, in this case I used it. But sometimes I need a shorter ```-```. I read 1 post about this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79141/is-there-a-designated-symbol-for-the-negative-sign-in-say-16 but it seems it unusable for ```frac{}{}``` or something like that

Comment: I, personally, don't thnk that the unary minus sign should be graphically different from its binary version. The reason why the minus sign is longer than a hyphen is that it should be as wide as a plus sign, which makes especially sense if used in a tabular context etc. I am not a mathematician, but from a typographical point of view, there should be no difference between the glyphs except from spacing which should be narrower where the minus sign is used as unary operator.

Comment: From a ( not so) higher mathematical point of view, there’s no subtraction symbol and `$a-b$` is just shorthand for `$a+-b$`.

Comment: You could use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469724/82917

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment.

No, there is as far as I know no symbol for that, and there is no entry for a unary minus in the Unicode math tables. That is a bit strange, but maybe there was no real demand for it.

There was a ConTeXt user asking for the unary minus this summer. The simple implementation, to scale the minus sign (as in at least one of the answers in the question you link to in the comment) was used, and ended up in a macro `\um`. To get spacing right, we also added a new atom class, the `unary operators`.

Regarding accessibility and copying: Private unicode slots are used (there were in fact some more unary symbols added). The unary minus can nevertheless be copied from the pdf and pasted again, and then it will give the usual math minus (what else could one use?).

Below you see a few examples. As you see, the size of the minus is adapted to where it is used.

```
\setupbodyfont[modern]

\starttext
\startTEXpage[offset=1dk]
\dm{ \int_1^2 \left[(x+2)^{\frac{1}{2}} - (x+2)^{  -\frac{1}{2}}\right] \dd x }\par
\dm{ \int_1^2 \left[(x+2)^{\frac{1}{2}} - (x+2)^{\frac{\um1}{2}}\right] \dd x }\par
\dm{ \int_1^2 \left[(x+2)^{\frac{1}{2}} - (x+2)^{\um\frac{1}{2}}\right] \dd x }\par
\dm{ a + \um a = 0}
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

[image: Some examples with the unary minus]

Comment: The differential symbol should be upright.

Comment: Should and should, but you are right that it is in the question. One can do `\setupmathematics[differentiald=upright]` to get an upright differential d.

Comment: Personally, I define in the preamble `\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`, which I found on this site a few years ago.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that hack. In ConTeXt there is a differential atom class, and the spacing is controlled by spacing between different classes.