# How to prevent xcolor from influencing algebraic sign spacing?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, color

The `xcolor` package influences the spacing of the algebraic sign. How to prevent this behavior?

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Mathematical background**

The second example should be treated as a binary operator instead of an unary operator.

See: [Unary vs. binary operator spacing in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/typesetting-of-negative-versus-minus)

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\(1 + 2\)

\(1 {\color{gray} + 2}\)

\end{document}
```

**Workaround**

By manually adjusting the spacing...

```
\(1 {\color{gray}\,+\,2}\)
```

Comment: `\(1 \textcolor{gray}{{} + 2}\)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An explicit brace group creates a `sub_mlist` which will always be assigned class `mathord` (if I'm not mistaken).  You can easily work around that problem by just using `\begingroup...\endgroup` instead of braces.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\(1 + 2\)

\(1 \begingroup\color{gray} + 2\endgroup\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the color but the group:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\(1 + 2\)

\(1 {+ 2}\)

\(1 {{} + 2}\)

\(1 {\color{gray} + 2}\)

\(1 {\color{gray}{} + 2}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]