# Setting two optimizations problems equal to each other in optidef

Tags: optidef

Below, I wrote what I want to express (and its output) without optidef. Since all other optimization problem equations in this paper are written in optidef, I would like this one to be as well. However, I cannot figure it out and would appreciate any help.

```
\begin{equation}
    \max_{\textbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}} f(\textbf{x}) = \min_{\textbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}} -f(\textbf{x})
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! It's not clear why you want to use something meant for a different target. By the way, it should be `\mathbf{x}` and not `\textbf{x}`.

Comment: Are you unsure about _what_ to write, or about _how_ to write it? The first question is off-topic here (you could try the [Math.SE] site), the second question is on-topic but then you need to provide the answer to the first question first.

Comment: I think you are looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112820/128658

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. What I am unsure about is how to write it. For example, I know if I wanted to describe the LHS using the optidef package it would be:

```
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{mini}|l|
    {\textbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}}{f(\mathbf{x})}
    {}{}
\end{mini}
```

What I'm looking to do is use the optidef package to write what I wrote in my question above. I hope this clarified the question.